# Spring: import a module with specified environment

Tags: spring

Is there anything that can achieve the equivalent of the below:

```
<import resource="a.xml">
    <prop name="key" value="a"/>
</import>

<import resource="a.xml">
    <prop name="key" value="b"/>
</import>
```

Such that the beans defined in resouce a would see the property key with two different values? The intention would be that this would be used to name the beans in the imports such that resource a.xml would appear:

```
<bean id="${key}"/>
```

And hence the application would have two beans named `a` and `b` now available with the same definition but as distinct instances. I know about prototype scope; it is not intended for this reason, there will be many objects created with interdepednencies that are not actually prototypes. Currently I am simply copying a.xml, creating b.xml and renaming all the beans using the equivalent of a `sed` command. I feel there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that PropertyPlaceholderConfigurers work on a per container basis, so you can't achieve this with xml imports.

Re `The application would have two beans named a and b now available with the same definition but as distinct instances`

I think you should consider creating additional application contexts(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext for example)  manually, using your current application context as the parent application context.
So your `many objects created with interdependencies` sets will reside in its own container each.

However, in this case you will not be able to reference `b`-beans from `a`-container.

**update** you can postprocess the bean definitions(add new ones) manually by registering a [BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html)  specialized bean, but this solution also does not seem to be easy.

OK, here's my rough attempt to import xml file manually:

disclaimer: I'm very bad java io programmer actually so double check the resource related code :-)

```
public class CustomXmlImporter implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    }

    private Map<String, String> properties;

    public void setProperties(Map<String, String> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    private void readXml(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = new ClassPathResource(this.classpathXmlLocation).getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
        try {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream);
            try {
                sc.useDelimiter("\\A");
                if (!sc.hasNext())
                    throw new AssertionError();
                String entireXml = sc.next();

                PropertyPlaceholderHelper helper = new PropertyPlaceholderHelper("${",
                        "}", null, false);
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.putAll(this.properties);
                String newXml = helper.replacePlaceholders(entireXml, props);
                reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ByteArrayResource(newXml.getBytes()));

            } finally {
                sc.close();
            }

        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
    }

    private String classpathXmlLocation;

    public void setClassPathXmlLocation(String classpathXmlLocation) {
        this.classpathXmlLocation = classpathXmlLocation;
    }

    public String getClassPathXmlLocation() {
        return this.classpathXmlLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(
            BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(registry);
        readXml(reader);
    }
}
```

XML configuration:

```
<bean class="CustomXmlImporter">
    <property name="classPathXmlLocation" value="a.xml" />
    <property name="properties">
        <map>
            <entry key="key" value="a" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="CustomXmlImporter">
    <property name="classPathXmlLocation" value="a.xml" />
    <property name="properties">
        <map>
            <entry key="key" value="b" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

this code loads the resources from classpath. I would think twice before doing something like that, anyway, you can use this as a starting point.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like this could be useful but I was hoping I would be able to do it from the Spring XML itself (it's a boring story but basically that's how we're setup to do this at the moment - not that it can't change it would just take longer than I would want to do it in).

Comment: @cyborg I don't think that there will be a reliable way to do this because the some beans will be defined twice if you forget to supply them the unique ids, the same thing is about the inner interdependencies. There some XML specific tools like `<ref local="xxx">` but they are merely compile time checks, bean resolving is determined almost exclusively by the container(its bean definitions and hierarchy), while XML configuration is secondary and is just a source of bean definitions.

Comment: That's what I suspected from what I could find. As I say however the current way that this is setup isn't conducive to your solution. However I am thinking that I could probably create my own Bean within the existing XML context that would load a specified XML file with the appropriate context and rename then according to my scheme (presumably would need a modification of the bean factory for this).

Comment: So it seems that you can solve this task with BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor / XmlBeanDefinitionReader It's interesting what was the solution of the problem.